# Why are the number of one qubit quantum gates uncountably infinite?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information

I keep running into this statement everywhere I go, and the source is never quoted. Is it because the entries for the matrix representing the gate are complex numbers and hence uncountably infinite? Where do I find a source for this?

Answer (score 1):

All phase-shifting operators, i.e. matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\
0&e^{i\theta}\\
\end{pmatrix}$, with arbitrary $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$, are gates. There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ of these.

Comment: $\aleph_1,$ if $\theta \in \mathbf{R}.$

Comment: @MarkH We know $|[0, 2\pi)| = |\mathbf{R}| = 2^{\aleph_{0}}$, but it's unsettled/unknown if $2^{\aleph_{0}}=\aleph_{1}$ (this is continuum hypothesis).

Comment: Sorry, Mark H was pointing out a mistake in my answer (I had written aleph_0), then I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most general transformation implemented by a *unitary* gate is of the form
$$
U=e^{i\xi}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\
-b^*&a^*\end{array}\right)\, , \tag{1}
$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\vert a\vert^2+\vert b\vert^2=1$.  A convenient way to reparametrize this is with $a=e^{i\varphi}\cos\theta$ and $b=e^{i\gamma}\sin\theta$, with $0\le \xi,\varphi,\gamma \le 2\pi$ and $0\le \theta\le \pi$.

As there is no other constraint on an *arbitrary* $2\times 2$ unitary, there are clearly infinitely many possible 4-tuples $(\xi,\varphi,\theta,\gamma)$, and moreover any range of the parameter is dense on its range.  That's enough to show what you want.